SSL Errors when Accessing Cloudflare Sites through Wireguard VPN
I'm running Pi-hole, PiVPN, and Unbound on an ARM Compute Instance from Oracle Cloud. My client is a Windows machine behind CGNAT. When connected to PiVPN, I'm experiencing issues accessing websites that are hosted behind Cloudflare (e.g., ChatGPT, Claude AI, Pluralsight). On Chromium-based browsers, these websites return either ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR or ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR. On Firefox and its forks, the same websites return SSL_ERROR_RX_MALFORMED_SERVER_HELLO.
What I've Done So Far
In my attempt to diagnose the root cause of this issue, I uninstalled Pi-hole, PiVPN, and Unbound completely. Then I used wireguard-install to create a Wireguard server. After connecting to the server, I tried to access those websites, but they all returned the same error. I also tried adjusting the MTU value from 1420 down to 1280, but it didn't resolve the issue. When I attempted to go lower, the WireGuard app for Windows displayed an error: Unable to configure adapter network settings.
I am at a loss as to what to do next. Since I don't have much knowledge in diagnosing SSL errors or network-related issues, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Debug logs

Pi-hole: https://pb.envs.net/?384e07e675146a58#buZLxqVM92m7w8N84ZWUg24KLEKV1iqamLgEvGHCygC

PiVPN: https://pb.envs.net/?219e94fb105f6001#5DroCbEBa95BQhLxKXcg4beGggLkHCRGBcemfF94Twm3

Unbound Configuration: https://pb.envs.net/?ad43cd3d1a71d285#JBqkVydBiyixNB4RXQJBfn8KBjBCP1XXBwAWhhaynCCN


Firewall rules

IPv4: https://pb.envs.net/?cb8577972dba2979#y3m5J8aFrWubgoXjhcCuhjAa9W9pzpm4DWZuySAugbS
IPv6: https://pb.envs.net/?397a1d512f84976e#3ScAxK7mztp46w73ABr5Le4xsSM7Vwvky9ZPyeGX2nfB


It looks like the problem wasn't related to WireGuard or Oracle's network. It was caused by GoodbyeDPI running on my Windows machine.
